# Getting the window coordinates in MonoGame

Tags: c#, windows, monogame

What I'm actually trying to do, is to get the mouse coordinates inside a windowed game. So far, I've only found ways to retrieve the screen coordinates of the mouse. Therefore, I would like to know the position of the window, so that I can subtract that from the mouse's screen coordinates in order to get the mouse's window coordinates.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Mouse.GetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mouse.getstate.aspx)? It returns a MouseState with X and Y properties on it. The documentation on MSDN is pretty sparse, but if you look carefully at documentation for the specific [X](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x.aspx) and [Y](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.y.aspx) properties you'll see that it returns a position relative to the upper left corner of the window which is more in line with what your after.

> MouseState.X - Horizontal position of the mouse cursor in relation to the upper-left corner of the game window.
>
> MouseState.Y - Vertical position of the mouse cursor in relation to the upper-left corner of the game window.

The advantage of doing this way is that it's not platform specific, so if you port your game to another platform in the future, the code won't have to change.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :-D
For some reason, I was using Mouse.GetCursorPos(out point), which gave me the screen coordinates. :-)